# How to access client side scripts from Source View smart tag designer by using GetClientScriptsInDocument

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2015, windows-forms-designer

I am trying to get the Script node block of ASP page and modify it dynamically, through code implementation. In order to do that I have a custom wizard (Component Designer) which I am opening from **Design View** or **[Source View](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dke0646y(v=vs.100).aspx)** (ASP page view). I have already defined  block in the asp markup. If I open the designer (with the smart tag) from the Design View, **[GetClientScriptsInDocument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.design.webformsrootdesigner.getclientscriptsindocument(v=vs.90).aspx)** is returning the existing  node and I can modify it (Add a javascript function for example), although If I open the designer from the Source View, then **GetClientSciptsInDocument** is returning null.

Part of my code is from "Pro ASP.NET Extensibility" book, I am using it to get the designer host (Usually Visual Studio), and from there the RootDesigner (WebFormsRootDesigner class) and client scripts.

***Code snippet:***

```
internal ScriptNodeCollection GetScriptNodes()
{
    IDesignerHost host = this.designer.Component.Site.GetService(typeof(IDesignerHost)) as IDesignerHost;
    WebFormsRootDesigner root = host.GetDesigner(host.RootComponent) as WebFormsRootDesigner;

    if (root == null) return null;
    ClientScriptItemCollection scriptItems = root.GetClientScriptsInDocument();
    ....
}
```

(*this*) is of type DesignerHelper (custom class) which inherits **System.Windows.Forms.Design.ControlDesigner**

Is this some kind of a .NET limitation and the script node block is accessible only with the Design View when custom designer is used, or I am missing something?